# Doctrine 2 erro select distinct

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

today I went for consultation with select distinct and my doctrine Symfony 2 returned a weird error ...

```
"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 46 near '(select distinct': Error: Class '(' is not defined."
```

My query is :

```
$em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$q = $em2->createQuery("select count(num_linhas) as qnt_clientes from (select distinct p.cliente
from pedido as p, cliente as c, nivel_pontuacao as nv, pedido_item as pit
where p.id = pit.pedido 
AND p.cliente = c.id
AND nv.id = c.nivel_pontuacao 
AND p.vencimento >= CURRENT_DATE - tempo_medicao*INTERVAL '1' month group by p.empresa, p.id) as num_linhas");
                $entities = $q->getResult();
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Select distinct is not a table.

Comment: Select distinct is a table .. The query works correctly using the pgAdmin ... :(